# Compilation Python 3.6.5 static binary for arm32 fail

Tags: android, python, linux, compilation

I'm trying, on Debian 9.4 x64, to compiling static Python binaries for arm32.
I have initialy:

- downloaded the "Gzipped source tarball" source file from:
  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/
- extracted source files in: /python3.6.5/
- downloaded and extract "binutils-gold-2.29.1-16.1.armv7hl.rpm" by cmd line:

  - `rpm -qlp /python3.6.5/binutils-gold-2.29.1-16.1.armv7hl.rpm`
- try to compile the binary with this following command:

  - `./configure --build=arm --prefix="$PWD"/out LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -Wl,--export-dynamic" CPPFLAGS=-static CXXFLAGS=-static CFLAGS="-Os -static" LDFLAGS=-static LD=ld.gold`
- And i get this errors:

  - `/usr/bin/ld: BFD assertion (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28 as failed ../../bfd/elflink.c:14098`
  - `/usr/bin/ld: BFD (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28 internal error, aborting at ../../bfd/elf64-x86-64.c:6137 in elf_x86_64_finish_dynamic_symbol`
  - `/usr/bin/ld: Thanks to report this anomaly.`
  - `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
  - `Makefile:561 : the recipe for the "python" target has failed`
    -`make: *** [python] Error 1`
- I'm trying to find how i could fix this error, but unfortunatly the support webpage on Python website isn't helpfull (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically).

**Finally, I would like to compile Python 3.6.5 for all processor platforms on which Android can run (arm32, aarm64, x86_x64, mips, mipsx64,...),  to ultimately get a single binary file (i will repeat tasks for all other archs when i will have done with arm32).**

**So one file for each architectures cited, not multiple files/folders.
In a static way to avoid any dependencies with external libraries.
I chose to carry out the build operations, but if other less hazardous and simpler solutions exist i am taker.**

NB: all cmd line has been made through LXTerminal on root session by default.

Thanks by advance for help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?